# Form validation on generated fields with ng-messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For a day I fiddled around with getting form validation to work with the new ng-messages on generated fields with no success. I read in the angular documentation and on a github issue ng-repeat is not supported by ng-messages because it does not interpolate its fields. So, I decided to go the jquery route build the dom myself compile it and replace the element with my generated code, which after of course I don't get to work either. So some help would be much appreciated. Here's my html:

```
....
    <app-field ng-repeat="field in fields" field="field" ng-model="selected[field.name]" form="form" type="input"></app-field>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="field1s">static field 1</label>
        <input name="field1s" type="text" ng-model="selected['field1']" class="form-control" required="">
        <ng-messages for="form['field1'].$error">
            <ng-message when="required">Is required</ng-message>
        </ng-messages>
        <label for="field2s">static field 2</label>
        <input name="field2s" type="text" ng-model="selected.field2" class="form-control" required="" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="2">
        <ng-messages for="form.field2s.$error">
            <ng-message when="required">Is required</ng-message>
            <ng-message when="maxlength">Max length 10</ng-message>
            <ng-message when="minlength">MIn length 2</ng-message>
        </ng-messages>
    </fieldset>
```

I've added some statically typed fields too so i could monitor the data source and the form. The directive app-field generates the dom which is cooked up with some jquery soup but it turned out to work quite well. I mean the generated dom looks like it is supposed to but ... but compiled it does not agree with angular, angular doesn't throw any errors but it just refuses to bind the dynamic fields to the form correctly. It updates the underlying object but does not do form validation let alone trigger the ng-messages and according to this post: [Angularjs: Form validation on input field generated by directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366329/angularjs-form-validation-on-input-field-generated-by-directive) I see no reason why it shouldn't. Here's a plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzC4jS9M9Ev5i6gxUVxB?p=preview

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Not really a solution, but according to @yearofmoo on twitter, "With the next release of Angular 1.4 (maybe 1.3) you will be able have ngMessages render server-side errors via ngRepeat. More details soon."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ng-form element inside every ng-repeat for dynamic field validation to work. I have fixed the problem in below plunker for field 1. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xQTLDa3TptXky8KIcSsh?p=preview

```
<form name="form">

<ng-form name="myform">
    <input name="field1s" type="text" ng-model="selected['field1']" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/">
            <ng-messages for="form.myform['field1s'].$error">
                <ng-message when="required">Is required</ng-message>
                <ng-message when="pattern">alpha error </ng-message>
            </ng-messages>
</ng-form>

</form>
```

I have commented out the custom JQuery code you had written. Since it is no longer required.

Please refer to this - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10165 for more info. on this problem.